# Zoom option in Smith chart

Tags: vcl, teechart, c++builder-6

Is zoom available for the Steema Smith chart? Polar chart types support this option. VCL cbuilder 6 version is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom and scroll is not supported in Smith series. It's on the wish-list to be considered for inclusion in future releases. Also, at [the version info page](http://www.steema.com/versioninfo/vcl), you can see that TeeChart support for C++ Builder 6 was discontinued last May. So, it is most unlikely that this functionality is ever implemented for this environment.